# Why the return value of my vector function is always 1?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I am new to the community. I want to ask a question about my code. I want to return `std::vector` from my function `dec2Bin`.

In main, when I call this function, I only get one value inside my vector. I don't know what is wrong with it, can someone help me please. This is the code I have

```
vector<int> dec2Bin(int n){
    vector<int> v;
    if (n == 0){
        v.push_back(0);
        return v;
    }

    else if (n == 1){
        v.push_back(1);
        return v;
    }

    else{
        v.push_back(n%2);
        return dec2Bin(n/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to return anything else? Your function is written to return either a vector with `0` in it or a vector with `1` in it (first two branches of `if`). The vector formed in the third branch of your `if` is never returned and never participates in anything at all.

Comment: What are you calling it with? Since you are new, you should read this: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Make an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't you think you need to pass `v` in the recursion, instead of creating a local `v`?

Comment: @AnT Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @DeanSeo I wanted my function to only take one argument, and return a vector containing it's binary representation.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox thanks, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` case mutates `v` but otherwise ignores it, returning only what it got from the recursive call, so the actual behavior is to repeatedly recurse after dividing by 2, eventually devolving to the `n == 0` or `n == 1` case, which produces a size `1` `vector`, then returns it up the call stack with no further modification.

If you want more than one value, perhaps change the `else` case to:

```
else{
    v = dec2Bin(n/2);
    v.push_back(n%2);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I understand now why it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass `v` to deeper recursions of the function, so at every recursion it simply creates a new `v` and returns it. You need to pass it to future recursive calls:

```
vector<int> dec2Bin(int n, vector<int>& v){
    if (n == 0){
        v.push_back(0);
        return v;
    }
    else if (n == 1){
        v.push_back(1);
        return v;
    }
    else{
        v.push_back(n%2);
        return dec2Bin(n/2, v);
    }
}
```

and optionally create an overload for the default calling convention:

```
vector<int> dec2Bin(int n){
    vector<int> v;
    dec2Bin(n, v);
    return v;
}
```

Alternatively, you can let `v` receive the constructed vector from deeper calls, as [*ShadowRanger*'s answer](/a/48070653/5958455) does.

Comment: There's no "need" to do that. The OP's approach with local `v` is perfectly fine. The OP just needs to remember to properly combine (concatenate) the results of "this" call and the recursive call, as shown in @ShadowRanger's answer.

Comment: @AnT I'm curious about the quotes around the word *need*.

Comment: I'm quoting your usage of the word. Your answer said "You *need* to pass it...", implying that this is somehow *necessary* to rethink the whole approach. It is not necessary. The original OP's approach is fine as is. There's simply a bug in the code.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to both pass the vector by reference, and return it

Comment: @AnT Good point, but maybe the OP's approach(or intention) is actually passing `v`, *originally*, given the fact that the OP didn't write the copy operation `v = dec2Bin(...)`. At least that's what I thought of. :)